# Authentication Required when sending mail via exim4 and gmail

Tags: authentication, gmail, exim

hey guys a have problems with sending mail via sendmail over exim4 and gmail from my server; i created new email on gmail, configured exim to work as a smarthost but im getting error

```
SMTP error from remote mail server after MAIL FROM:<root@localhost> SIZE=1330: host smtp.gmail.com [64.233.162.108]: 530-5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n530 5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError r12sm5237727ljd.6 - gsmtp
```

here is my /etc/exim4/update-exim4.conf.conf

```
dc_eximconfig_configtype='smarthost'
dc_other_hostnames=''
dc_local_interfaces='127.0.0.1'
dc_readhost='host.ru'
dc_relay_domains=''
dc_minimaldns='false'
dc_relay_nets=''
dc_smarthost='smtp.gmail.com::587'
CFILEMODE='644'
dc_use_split_config='true'
dc_hide_mailname='false'
dc_mailname_in_oh='true'
dc_localdelivery='mail_spool'
```

and my /etc/exim4/passwd.client

```
smtp.gmail.com:check@gmail.com:pass123
```

what am i do wrong guys ?

Comment: Maybe somebody hacked `check@gmail.com` because you put a password out into the open?